# Can I mix shipping options when using the AddFixedPriceItem .NET SDK on eBay

Tags: .net, ebay-api

I am using the AddFixePriceItem api call to list items for sale on eBay. This works well when we are using the calculated shipping type, and several options for shipping. We want to be able to offer free shipping with our first option for domestic shipping and then Calculated for options 2 and 3. Is this possible? I have tried different mixes of shipping type and setting shipping cost to 0 and setting the free shipping property to true for option 1 but always get an error. It seems if I use free shipping I can only offer one option for domestic shipping. What I have tried is Setting shipping type to calculated, and option 1 to Free with 0 cost. This produced and error. Then tried setting shipping type to Flat with option 1 to Free and 0 cost. This produced an error. If I set the shipping type to Flat and only one option with Free shipping = true and 0 cost then it goes through. Are the other properties that need to be set?

Comment: This question can be ignored. The issue I have found is a difference between the way the eBay Sandbox displays listing shipping info and the way the actual site does. They are not the same. If I put in a zip code for ship to on the sandbox listing it changes the first domestic option to Free as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Free shipping option as true in **AddItems** call in trading **API** for allowing free shipping for a product.
For a product, a **SHIPPING TYPE** can be only one that is **FLAT** or **CALCULATED**. You can add multiple shipping options whether domestic or international with different shipping cost.

Domestic shipping services can be added under the **ShippingServiceOptions** element and international services can be added in the **IntenationalShippingServiceOption** element in the **AddItems** Call.